# Android 8.1 emulator - embedded Google Map does not work in my app

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-mapview, android-8.1-oreo

Latest Android 8.1 emulator from Google. Neither [PlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) nor any embedded map view in my app isn'a able to show map. It only shows blank window instead. PlacePicker from google shows empty widnow instead on map and unable to load any place.
I have set map api key, Google Play services etc correctly and they work just fine on older Android version (including emulators). Should it be considered as bug in 8.1 developer build, or I rather need to configure somehting else? Google Maps appliaction shows map just fine.

P.S. I can't see anything related to this issue in logcat.

[edit]
Ok, I found this in logcat while loading map:

> E/Google Maps Android API: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports
>   devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

However, I'm using OpenGL ES 3.1:

[image]